# PyTorch: Is retain_graph=True necessary in alternating optimization?

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, mixture-model

I'm trying to optimize two models in an alternating fashion using PyTorch. The first is a neural network that is changing the representation of my data (ie a map f(x) on my input data x, parameterized by some weights W). The second is a Gaussian mixture model that is operating on the f(x) points, ie in the neural network space (rather than clustering points in the input space. I am optimizing the GMM using expectation maximization, so the parameter updates are analytically derived, rather than using gradient descent.

I have two loss functions here: the first is a function of the distances ||f(x) - f(y)||, and the second is the loss function of the Gaussian mixture model (ie how 'clustered' everything looks in the NN representation space). What I want to do is take a step in the NN optimization using both of the above loss functions (since it depends on both), and then do an expectation-maximization step for the GMM. The code looks like this (I have removed a lot since there is a ton of code):

```
data, labels = load_dataset()
net = NeuralNetwork()
net_optim = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=0.05, weight_decay=1)

# initialize weights, means, and covariances for the Gaussian clusters
concentrations, means, covariances, precisions = initialization(net.forward_one(data)) 

for i in range(1000):
    net_optim.zero_grad()
    pairs, pair_labels = pairGenerator(data, labels) # samples some pairs of datapoints
    outputs = net(pairs[:, 0, :], pairs[:, 1, :]) # computes pairwise distances
    net_loss = NeuralNetworkLoss(outputs, pair_labels) # loss function based on pairwise dist.

    embedding = net.forward_one(data) # embeds all data in the NN space

    log_prob, log_likelihoods = expectation_step(embedding, means, precisions, concentrations)
    concentrations, means, covariances, precisions = maximization_step(embedding, log_likelihoods)

    gmm_loss = GMMLoss(log_likelihoods, log_prob, precisions, concentrations)

    net_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    gmm_loss.backward(retain_graph=True)
    net_optim.step()
```

Essentially, this is what is happening:

1. Sample some pairs of points from the dataset
2. Push pairs of points through the NN and compute network loss based on those outputs
3. Embed all datapoints using the NN and perform a clustering EM step in that embedding space
4. Compute variational loss (ELBO) based on clustering parameters
5. Update neural network parameters using both the variational loss and the network loss

However, to perform (5), I am required to add the flag `retain_graph=True`, otherwise I get the error:

`RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time, but the buffers have already been freed. Specify retain_graph=True when calling backward the first time.`

It seems like having two loss functions means that I need to retain the computational graph?

I am not sure how to work around this, as with `retain_graph=True`, around iteration 400, each iteration is taking ~30 minutes to complete. Does anyone know how I might fix this? I apologize in advance – I am still very new to automatic differentiation.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing

```
total_loss = net_loss + gmm_loss
total_loss.backward()
```

Note that the gradient of net_loss w.r.t gmm weights is 0 thus summing the losses won't have any effect. 
Here is a good thread on pytorch regarding the retain_graph. https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/what-exactly-does-retain-variables-true-in-loss-backward-do/3508/24